# Android icon sometimes open new app sometimes brings up old app, help!

Tags: java, android

I have an android app which i have written, which exhibits some strange behaviour.

When i have an app open, say with three acitivties in the stack

A - B - C

where a is the entry point and C is the currently viewed activity, if i press the home button and reselect the icon for my app sometimes i see A, which on pressing the back button i can see the task now contains the activities

A - B  - C - A

and sometime it just reopens the app in the last state

A - B - C

which is what i want to happen. Could anyone inform me of why the inconsitant behaviour is happening. On both cases i press the icon strait after exiting the app via the home key.

## Thanks for any help!

ps i have also asked this question on anddev [here](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=32699#32699)

Answer (score 0):

It sometime happens if you are running your app through a shortcut on your desktop. Delete shortcut and re install and you should be fine.

Comment: Really?! That seems very shoddy behavior, does this happen on the emulator only or actual devices also? I cant imagine google would let a bug so monumental (and simple) through the development process?! Please give more details if possible...